# can you use a pvc pipe cutter to cut waste pipe

Tags: pipe

When piping up the shower waste, it's inevitable you willl need to cut the pipe shorted at some point.

When I was training to be an electrian, I used something similar to [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plastic-Cutting-Cutter-KingCut-42/dp/B07C6HKP2J/ref=pd_vtph_tr_t_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07C6HKP2J&pd_rd_r=8e7a666e-8dea-11e8-915b-ad4d0e8dff36&pd_rd_w=wQQ3g&pd_rd_wg=JOiiR&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_p=3950386175001893296&pf_rd_r=9585G62S26R1931B9XEP&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&psc=1&refRID=9585G62S26R1931B9XEP) to cut conduit. Would I be able to use it to cut waste pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Conduit is PVC. You can cut DWV pipe the same way. Be aware that that tool has a maximum diameter of 42 mm. Your shower drain may be larger than that.